# GCC - invalid optimization when using POSIX signals

Tags: c, signals, compiler-optimization

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int current = 0;

void sigint_handle(int sig) {
    printf("sigint: %d\n", current);
}

int main()
{
    sigset(SIGINT, sigint_handle);

    while (1) {
        current++;
        // if (current % 1000000 == 0) printf("hey\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with optimization level `-O0` using GCC 7.2.0, this code works as expected. However, with any other optimization level, sending sigint will print out `sigint: 0` each time. It will also work correctly regardless of optimization when the output line is uncommented.

Am I missing something about signals, is this a bug in gcc or is this the intended behavior (and if so, why?)?

Comment: Declare `current` as type `volatile sigatomic_t`.

Comment: What else are you missing? Calling `printf()` in a signal handler is undefined behavior.  Only async-signal-safe functions can be safely called from a signal handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing an object with static storage duration and type other than `volatile sig_atomic_t` from a signal handler results in undefined behavior. The source for this is (for C11):

> 7.14.1.1 The signal function
>
> [...]
>
> 5 If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or...

POSIX likely will (possible future direction, not decided yet) define the behavior under slightly more relaxed conditions; in some sense it mistakenly already does, via loopholes with use of AS-safe functions. I have an open issue on the Austin Group issue tracker about this topic:

http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=728